# Limit Child div using tinySort?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, tinysort

I am using [tinySort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) to filter dynamically created child divs, which works great. However, I would also like to restrict the amount of child divs aftersorting. eg.. Only have the top 5 sorted divs.

This is the current code I used to sort.

```
tinysort("#results > div", {
                    order: "desc",
                    attr: 'id'
    });
```

I thought of using something like this  `if (($this).children().length < 5)`

But, I am unsure of how to incoorperate it into tinySort, or if this functionality already exists?

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

DOM structure :

```
<div id="results" class="results">
 <div id="205" class="results-section">
  <div class="details">
    <h2>115</h2>
     </div>
      <div id="time">
       <h3>7</h3>
   <small>minutes</small>
  </div>
 </div>
<div id="196" class="results-section">
  <div class="details">
    <h2>115</h2>
     </div>
      <div id="time">
       <h3>7</h3>
   <small>minutes</small>
  </div>
 </div>
<div id="180" class="results-section">
  <div class="details">
    <h2>115</h2>
     </div>
      <div id="time">
       <h3>7</h3>
   <small>minutes</small>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best you can do is hide the elements after sorting. Something like this

```
$('#results > div').tsort({
    order: "desc",
    attr: 'id'
}).filter(function (i, el) {
    return i > 4; // this way if the other elements need some other style
}).hide();
```

Here is an example **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/9VT8g/23/**

---

Or even simpler

```
$('#results > div').tsort({
    order: "desc",
    attr: 'id'
}).slice(5).hide(); // strictly hide rest except first 5
```

Second demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/9VT8g/24/**